# Android : change the position of alert dialog icon

Tags: user-interface, android

I have an alert dialog in android xml file.my alert dialog has an icon in the left side of it.I want to change the position of the icon to the right side.
I **dont want** to use **custum dialog** too

like this :

[image]

Comment: are you using localization? Are these your default strings? I think if you put them in the arabic folder you can achieve the behaviour.

Comment: The localization to Persian should work

Comment: my language direction is rtl(right to left) and I want to move the icon to the right side of dialog's title

Comment: Do a custom dialog, I believe is the only simple-way to do it :)

Answer (score 5):

For setting layout direction of alert dialog to RTL you can use the  `OnShowListener` method.

after setting title, message, etc., use this method:

```java
dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL); // set title and message direction to RTL
    }
});

dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

a) If you have it as a drawable in the dialog title (TextView), just use drawableRight

```
android:drawableRight="@drawable/yourIcon"
```

b) If it is an ImageView/ImageButton in a RelativeLayout, use alignParentRight

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

c) If it is an ImageView/ImageButton in a LinearLayout, put it after the TextView

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="some text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/yourIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to create a style tag in res/values/styles and write :

```
<style name="alertDialog LayoutDirection">
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
</style>
```

and then add this after alert dialog initializing in your activity :

```
alertDialog.setView(R.style.alertDialog);
```

for example :

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setMessage("حذف بشه؟")
                    .setCancelable(true);
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("آره", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("نه", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nooo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.setView(R.style.alertDialog);
```

Answer (score -1):

Im afraid you have no other choice then customizing.
The common dialogs are pretty static in UI changes. You can set another title, buttons or change the image but you can't reposition them.